# @UpdateTimestamp is not updating with latest timestamp Spring Boot Data JPA

Tags: java

I am using Spring Boot JPA and trying to update using @Query Annotation.

I have a field to update whenever there is an update to a record by @UpdateTimestamp.

I see the record being updated with the right value however last updated timestamp value is not being updated.

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

import javax.persistence.*;

import java.util.Date;


@Entity
@Table(name ="testing")
public class Testing {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @CreationTimestamp
    private Date creat_ts;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Date update_ts;

    public Testing(){

    }

    public Testing(String name, Long id){
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

```
public interface TestingRepo extends JpaRepository<Testing,Long> {

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query("update Testing t set t.name=:name where t.id=:test_id")
    void updateLoadName(@Param("name") String loadname, @Param("test_id") Long testid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The annotation `@UpdateTimestamp` is specific to Hibernate. Spring Data also supports this feature, using `@CreatedDate` and `@LastModifiedDate`. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#auditing

Since you seem to be using spring-data-jpa, I think it's better to use the Spring annotation.

Answer (score 0):

update statements side step entity lifecycle events including the update of creation and update statements.